# Cannot add onclick property to input viable

Tags: javascript, input, onclick

Easy points. Mystifying problem. Below is my code. I create a variable for my input button. I add an onclick function. I add the input variable to an existing div. But the onclick property does not appear. Please help.

```
    var newbutton = document.createElement('input');
    var addonclick = "'return sayhi('phrase')'";
    newbutton.onclick = addonclick;//does not work
    newbutton.type = 'button'; 
    document.getElementById('existingdiv').appendChild(newbutton);
```

...

```
    function sayhi(phrase){
        alert(phrase);
    }
```

Also does not work:

```
            newbutton.id = "buttonid";   
            ....              
            document.getElementById("buttonid").onload = '"return sayhi('phrase')"';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `newbutton.onclick = sayhi;` it will work. onclick expects a javascript that will be executed on click of that element. Here `addonclick` will be just a variable, there is nothing to execute on click of that element.

Comment: Ok but how do I pass a variable to sayhi? see edited question.

Comment: nevermind. I figured it out. I simply put newbutton.onclick = sayhi('phrase');

Comment: You can have add an anonymous function as click handler, and pass parameter from that. ex : newbutton.onclick = function() { sayhi(name); }

Comment: the only problem with your solution now is that the button clicks itself upon loading. Why does it do that and how do I stop it from doing that?

Comment: Why would it click itself? see the demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/ChaitanyaMunipalle/UJYZZ/ It is not triggering click on load

Comment: It executes on load with your solution. you have to use anonymous function to avoid that

Comment: You were correct. I was using the newbutton.onclick = sayhi('phrase'); method and it was looping, but your method avoids that issue. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

The onclick property takes a function not a string, e.g.

```
newbutton.onclick = function(){sayhi('phrase')};
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign sayhi to .onclick. Also give your button some text

```
var newbutton = document.createElement('input');
newbutton.onclick = sayhi;
newbutton.type = 'button';
newbutton.value = 'click'; 
document.getElementById('existingdiv').appendChild(newbutton);

function sayhi(){
    alert("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey did you tried this way:

```
function sayhi(){
        alert("hi");
    }

var newbutton = document.createElement('input');

    newbutton.onclick = sayhi;
    newbutton.type = 'button'; 
    document.getElementById('existingdiv').appendChild(newbutton);
```

Comment: Note that setting onclick to sayhi(); will actually run the function sayhi. Lose the brackets.